# How to tell python consumer to wait for client to bootup

Tags: python, docker, apache-pulsar, python-pulsar

I have a fundamental problem in a docker container where when I try to start create and start two images where the second image (python and some scripts) is dependent on the first image.

This causes the second image to error out and stop. How can I adopt my python script to consume on the client, to wait for the client boot-up?

*I don't think this problem is necessarily an Apache Pulsar problem, but here's some documentation for those interested*

[Apache Pulsar standalone](https://pulsar.apache.org/docs/en/standalone/)

[python api
docs](https://pulsar.apache.org/api/python/2.8.0-SNAPSHOT/)

**Consumer on Client**

```
import pulsar

def initialize_consumer():

    client = pulsar.Client('pulsar://localhost:6650')

    consumer = client.subscribe('my-topic', 'my-subscription')

    while True:
        msg = consumer.receive()
        try:
            output_string = f"Received message {msg.data()} id={msg.message_id()}"
            print(output_string)
            with open('./output.txt', 'a') as f:
                f.write(output_string + '\n')
            # Acknowledge successful processing of the message
            consumer.acknowledge(msg)
        except:
            # Message failed to be processed
            consumer.negative_acknowledge(msg)

    client.close()
```

Comment: What have you already tried?  Do any of the suggestions in [Docker Compose wait for container X before starting Y](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31746182/docker-compose-wait-for-container-x-before-starting-y) help you?

Comment: Yes it did actually. I literally just implemented a solution from that thread that's working for me. I'll post my "solution" here soon.

Answer (score 0):

This thread helped me since I had a Docker specific problem: [Docker Compose wait for container X before starting Y](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31746182/docker-compose-wait-for-container-x-before-starting-y)

I essentially added a `healthcheck` for my `standalone` image and then used the `restart: on-failure` for my `conprod` image and that seems to work.

I'd still be interested in a python centered solution in the actualy consumer function above.

`docker-compose.yaml` file ends up looking like this:

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  standalone:
    hostname: standalone
    container_name: standalone
    image: apachepulsar/pulsar:2.8.1
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
      - 6650:6650
    command: bin/pulsar standalone
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "nc", "-vz", "localhost", "6650"]
      interval: 20s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 5
    networks:
      - conprod
  conprod:
    hostname: conprod
    container_name: conprod
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 80:80
    restart: on-failure
    depends_on:
      - standalone
    networks:
      - conprod
networks:
  conprod:
```